Always gets stuck at - npm info run puppeteer@18.2.1 postinstall node_modules/puppeteer node install.js?
On a Windows 11 setup running npm install github:pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#webpack-exodus --verbose always gets stuck at npm info run puppeteer@18.2.1 postinstall node_modules/puppeteer node install.js in the verbose log.
I have left this open for several hours and tried multiple times but same results, what am I missing here?

Setting PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD system variable fixed this for me.
